# How to convert try-catch statements in octave to a Matlab form?

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, octave, centroid

I need to convert an old Octave code to Matlab R2017a form. Matlab is not understanding the to-be-mentioned code and it is giving the error :

> Undefined variable "lasterror" or class "lasterror.message".
>
> Error in computeCentroids (line 16)
>        msg = lasterror.message;

Mathworks are saying that "lasterror" is going to be—or already has been— deleted from more modern versions of Matlab. I personally am not familiar with `lasterror.message` nor with the try-catch pair. I Hope you help me.

**code:**

```
function centroids = computeCentroids(Xnum, Xcat, idx, K) 
[m n] = size([Xcat Xnum]);
centroids = zeros(K, n);
for i=1:K,
    indx = (idx(:,1)== i);
    try
        centroids(i,:) = [findMode(Xcat, indx) computeMean(Xnum, indx)];
    catch
        msg = lasterror.message;
        fprintf(strcat(msg, '\n'));
    end_try_catch
    end
end
.
.
.
.
end
```

Comment: Did you try reading [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html)? Catch the exception itself, don't rely on `lasterror`

Comment: If, for whatever reason, you do want to use `lasterror` then you need to store the structure returned by `lasterror` before trying to access its `message` field. Unlike Octave, MATLAB does not allow indexing into the return of a function without first assigning it to an intermediate variable.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html). You can print the error like this:

```
try
   %Error-maker
catch e 
    fprintf(1,'There was an error! The message was:\n%s',e.message);
end
```